# Input inside input-group div seems to have a max width and doesn't fill div

Tags: html, css, input, styles, width

I have an input inside an input-group division that is not expanding to the whole width of the div. It seems to reach a maximum width and doesn't ever get bigger even if a wider screen is used. Everything I see says to simply add a width in the style and also to add box-sizing: border-box but that isn't doing anything.

```
<style>
    .fitDiv{
            width:100%;
        }
        .fitContainer{
            width:99%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
</style>

<td class="minWidth-220">
    <div class="input-group fitDiv">
        <span id="ItemSearch" class="input-group-addon itemSearchIcon"          title="Item List">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </span>
        <input class = "form-control item-number fitContainer", id = "ItemNumber", Title = "Code">
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: Can you build a demo? Jsfiddle or stack snippets

Comment: [Your code works as posted.](https://jsfiddle.net/corss0jq/)

Comment: You forgot to include Bootstrap. Not sure I understand what the issue is from the fiddle though. https://jsfiddle.net/corss0jq/2/